# Index/Match & Aggregate

Tags: excel, vba

First some background;

I'm currently working on a small piece of Excel VBA code to quickly analyze data from an older analytical device which only outputs .txt files.

So, for multiply files in a folder, I already managed to import the generated .txt files and do some basic formatting. Using a combination of the index & match functions, I'm able to extract the necessary information (the concentration, so a number) for single components.

The problem;

Some components appear multiply times and I would like the sum of these components.

As example:

| Name | Concentration |
| --- | --- |
| Component1 | 10 |
| Component2 | 20 |
| Component3 | 30 |
| Component1 | 40 |

The code should return (on a dedicated second sheet):

| Name | Concentration |
| --- | --- |
| Component1 | 50 |
| Component2 | 20 |
| Component3 | 30 |

My code looks like this:

```
Sub INDEX_MATCH_COMPONENT()
'PURPOSE: Index component values out data sheet, the same matches are aggregated

Dim k As Integer

For k = 2 To 4     'Go through search criteria

'Where to drop values      Aggregate = sum up all matches       Where to find values, component names            Values to find, component names           Location concentration, value to return
Sheet2.Cells(k, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Aggregate(9, 3, WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet1.Range("C:C"), WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet2.Cells(k, 2).Value, Sheet1.Range("B:B"), 0)))

On Error Resume Next 'Ignore any errors due to missing values

Next k

End Sub
```

The code looks for the required components in sheet2 and matches them in sheet1, to return the concentration in the cells next to it.

When I run this code, only the found first value is shown. The code does not aggregate all 'Component1' matches. So I get:

| Name | Concentration |
| --- | --- |
| Component1 | 10 |
| Component2 | 20 |
| Component3 | 30 |

What is the problem here? Does an aggregate in combination with index/match not work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure all the names, like "Component1" are identical? And do not have leading or trailing spaces: " Component1" or "Component1 " etc

Comment: Just an idea - use PivotTable?

Comment: I agree with @RaymondWu, a PivotTable can do this. Turn subtotals & grand totals off for rows and columns. Report Layout in Tabular form. Your "Name" field as a row, and your "Concentration" as a Value Field. The Value field settings would be Sum.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm sure the names are identical. In addition to this, when I go through the code using the debug feature, the code just stops after the first match. So name mismatch certainly isn't the problem.

Comment: @RaymondWu I do not have a lot of experience with PivotTables but I will give it a go. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Wolfriner You have a pretty simple data set so you should be fine if you follow Toddleson's instruction.

Comment: `Match` is only going to return the first result it finds, which is why it isn't working the way you want. An alternative to look into would be to use `Sumifs` rather than `Aggregate`.

Comment: Try using [Power Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/group-by). You can group or summarizing rows,  import  files from a specific folder, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for helping me out. I had to figure out some other small issues but I got it working in the end. As Raymond Wu suggested a Pivot table is indeed the way to go.

So first the data is imported into an Excel sheet. After some formatting, the code generates a Pivot table from the data I need. From this Pivot table, the needed data is extracted and put it into a sheet with all results.

Code used to make the Pivot table:

```
Sub ComponentDataToPivot()
'Make a pivot table in order to aggregate all components

'Declare variables to hold row and column numbers that define source data cell range
Dim myFirstRow As Long
Dim myLastRow As Long
Dim myFirstColumn As Long
Dim myLastColumn As Long

'Declare variables to hold source and destination cell range address
Dim mySourceData As String
Dim myDestinationRange As String

'Declare object variables to hold references to source and destination worksheets, and new Pivot Table
Dim mySourceWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim myDestinationWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim myPivotTable As PivotTable

Worksheets.Add.Name = "Pivot"

'Identify source and destination worksheets. Add destination worksheet
With ThisWorkbook
    Set mySourceWorksheet = Worksheets("Processing")
    Set myDestinationWorksheet = Worksheets("Pivot")
End With

'obtain address of destination cell range
myDestinationRange = myDestinationWorksheet.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'identify row and column numbers that define source data cell range
myFirstRow = 34 'This is the most common line on average
myLastRow = 250
myFirstColumn = 5
myLastColumn = 8

'obtain address of source data cell range
With mySourceWorksheet.Cells
    mySourceData = .Range(.Cells(myFirstRow, myFirstColumn), .Cells(myLastRow, myLastColumn)).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
End With

'create Pivot Table cache and create Pivot Table report based on that cache
Set myPivotTable = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=mySourceWorksheet.Name & "!" & mySourceData).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=myDestinationWorksheet.Name & "!" & myDestinationRange, TableName:="PivotTableNewSheet")

'add, organize and format Pivot Table fields
With myPivotTable
    .PivotFields("Name").Orientation = xlRowField
    With .PivotFields("Amt/Area")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Position = 1
        .Function = xlSum
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    End With
  End With
End Sub
```

Followed up with the code below to extract the data I need:

```
Sub RetrieveComponentResults(ByVal StartRow)
'PURPOSE: Index group values out data sheet

Dim k As Integer

For SearchColumn = 22 To 32     'Go through search criteria, so in this case the group names

'Where to drop values                               Values to copy                                       Values to find, e.g. group names                              Where value to find can be found, eg group names
Worksheets("Results").Cells(SearchColumn, StartRow).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Pivot").Range("B:B"), WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Results").Cells(SearchColumn, 2).Value, Worksheets("Pivot").Range("A:A"), 0))

On Error Resume Next ' Ignore any missing values

Next SearchColumn

'Delete Sheet with Pivottable to allow next one to be generated
Worksheets("Pivot").Delete

End Sub
```

Again thanks for all the help, saved me a lot of work!

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA. Some assumptions made on where data is.

List unique values:

```
=Unique(A$2:A$5)
```

Sum function - copy down:

```
=SUM(FILTER(Sheet2!A$2:A$5,Sheet2!A$2:A$5=A2),0)
```